# What causes the Openid error: Received "invalidate_handle" from server

Tags: python, django, openid, django-authopenid

I'm new to openid, and I am getting an "invalidate_handle" and I have no idea what to do to fix it.
I'm using django_authopenid

```
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:28 2010] [error] Generated checkid_setup request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud with assocication AOxxxxxxxxOX5-V9oDc3-btHhFxzAcccccccccc2RTHgh    
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:29 2010] [error] Error attempting to use stored discovery information: <openid.consumer.consumer.TypeURIMismatch: Required type http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon not found in ['http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server', 'http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0', 'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup', 'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon', 'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0'] for endpoint <openid.consumer.discover.OpenIDServiceEndpoint server_url='https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud' claimed_id=None local_id=None canonicalID=None used_yadis=True >>  
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:29 2010] [error] Attempting discovery to verify endpoint  
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:29 2010] [error] Performing discovery on https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AOxxxxxxxxOX5-V9oDc3-btHhFxzAcccccccccc2RTHgh   
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:29 2010] [error] Received id_res response from https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud using association AOxxxxxxxxOX5-V9oDc3-btHhFxzAcccccccccc2RTHgh  
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:29 2010] [error] Using OpenID check_authentication  
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:29 2010] [error] op_endpoint  
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:29 2010] [error] claimed_id  
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:29 2010] [error] identity  
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:29 2010] [error] return_to  
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:29 2010] [error] response_nonce  
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:29 2010] [error] assoc_handle  
[Thu Apr 29 14:13:29 2010] [error] Received "invalidate_handle" from server https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
```

Comment: Hi, Did you find solution to your problem ? If yes, can you please post it ? I am having similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613454/internal-server-error-while-using-python-openid-with-google-authentication).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openid.invalidate_handle is the Provider's way of saying that your RP is sending an association that does not exist or has expired.  The RP is supposed to respond by deleting that association handle so it isn't reused in the future.  If you're always getting invalidate_handles in the response, then the RP you're using has a bug in it.