# Internal Server error while using Python OpenId with Google Authentication

Tags: python, django, openid, askbot

I have installed askbot.org on my local machine and When I tri to use google openid, I get following error. Here is full apache log. (I have replaced some hex strings)

http://bit.ly/apache_log

Can someone explain to me what could be problem ?

Answer (score 0):

From your log, this seems to be the big issue:

```
[Wed Mar 07 22:58:13 2012] [error] Received "invalidate_handle" from server
```

From the answer to this [question on invalidate_handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739886/what-causes-the-openid-error-received-invalidate-handle-from-server), it looks like a bug in the "Relying Party". I would double-check your configuration.